# How to decompress zlib data in hexadecimal form?

Tags: http, zip, compression, gzip, zlib

I am inspecting traffic from a mobile app. After disabling SSL pinning, Fiddler intercepts data from the app and the app's server. However, it is in hexadecimal form. The first 2 bytes are always 78 9C, so I believe that it is compressed by zlib. How do I decompress it?

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 3.5:

```
import zlib

s = '789ccbc80400013b00d2'
b = bytearray.fromhex(s)
z = zlib.decompress(b)
print(z)
```